# GitHub displaying boxes on chromium [Arch]

Tags: arch-linux, chromium, github, characters

I am running google chromium on Arch Linux.  When I go to GitHub, chromium displays little boxes instead of what is supposed to be there (Screencap: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZc2j.png).  GitHub displays correctly on Firefox in the same system.  How can I get chrome to display GitHub correctly?

EDIT: I installed all kinds of different fonts and followed the arch wiki's instructions on fonts, and it still isn't working